# Cannot open Gedit display on Ubuntu Server 12.04

Tags: 12.04, server, gedit

I just installed Ubuntu Server 12.04 32 bit. I need to perform the following command in a terminal window:

```
sudo gedit /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

First the gedit command did not work; therefore, I did:

```
sudo apt-get install gedit
```

Then I typed `sudo gedit /etc/samba.smb.conf` and now I am getting: `Cannot open display`

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you installed the GUI? *(can you see windows and desktop or only a terminal)*

Answer (score 2):

I used nano instead of gedit.

```
sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

Woo hoo, my Ubuntu Server is now working!!  :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing your server from a workstation using ssh, then you can't use graphical applications unless you set your DISPLAY variable to point to your workstation's X-Server. For system administrators, I would recommend learning your way around the vim editor. The learning curve is a bit steep in the beginning, but it's well worth it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nano or vim for editing configuration files. Both are preinstalled on  ubuntu server 12.04.